Why can't I use table names of aliased tables in WHERE clause?
Why won't SQL Server let me do this?  It gives me 3

The multi-part identifier ... could not be bound.

errors because I'm using the actual table name, not the table alias, to reference columns (this is a simplified example).
SELECT TS_USERS.ts_id, ts_Users.ts_name  
FROM ts_Users u  
WHERE ts_users.ts_id > 0;

of course this works
SELECT u.ts_id, u.ts_name  
FROM ts_Users u  
WHERE u.ts_id > 0;

It's like SQL Server forgets the actual table name once that table is aliased (within the context of the SELECT)?

It's not that it forgets the table name, it's that the code explicitly tells it to use a specific identifier for that table.  If the alias isn't intended to be used, don't specify it.

@david: As noted, this is a highly simplified example where the SQL for the SELECT statement is created by multiple functions and glued together.  The functions that generate parts of the SELECT don't have access to the other functions that build the "FROM" clause and establish the aliases.  I can't find where this behavior is documented in the SQL Server docs.

I'll give you a real life scenario where this happened: for years in the office I didn't answer to someone voicing "Thom" because there were three T(h)oms in the same room; it was confusing for all of us. As such we had TA (that's me!), TQ and TT; if someone said "T(h)om" none of us responded as we had long got fed up of turning around to something not relevant to us. If someone said "TA" they got my undivided attention. You're doing the same for your table; you've given it an alias and told it to respond to that. I didn't "forget" my name was Thom, even though I didn't answer to it.

Don't forget, as well, you can reference a table multiple times in the same statement. If you had SELECT * FROM dbo.users U JOIN dbo.users M ON U.ManagerID = M.UserID WHERE users.Name = N'Dave'; which table are you referencing in the WHERE?

@mnemotronic: "I can't find where this behavior is documented in the SQL Server docs." - If that's the real question being asked then it's entirely possible that this isn't explicitly documented and the behavior is implied based on what is otherwise documented, that a table alias creates a new custom identifier for that table within the scope of that query.  The behavior is observed and confirmed in your own testing, so whether or not any documentation clearly describes it in a way you expect it to doesn't make much difference.

Looks like you just have to remake your system that generates the sql, or use table name as alias as well

This behavior is what ANSI SQL defines.

@ThomA:  So, in your example, if someone walked in and said "I need to talk to TA", then everyone would all know it meant you.  I get that --- using the alias is the same as the table name.  Now suppose someone walked in and said (pretend the name below is your full name...) "I need to speak with Thomas Paul Anders" then would you: (A) Respond because that was your name and it was full and unambiguous or (B) Ignore the person because they didn't use your initials?  My example is like (A) except that I didn't use [server_name].[dbo].[tablename].  Which gives me something to investigate.

By using an alias [like u], you are telling SQL that within the context of this query, henceforth only refer to the table as u and only u.
If you have a way to turn off the alias when generating that command, try that. Or else try making the alias the same as the tablename.
